# Items could not be retrieved, Internal server error [Heroku - GitHub Integration]

Tags: github, heroku, deployment, heroku-cli

## [HEROKU - GitHub Integration]

When I'm trying to connect my GitHub repo with Heroku it's giving me this
error

### **Items could not be retrieved, Internal server error**

on the right-hand side in the red box

[image]

Comment: Could you find the solution?

Comment: Yes, for this i put my code on Heroku server from the Github

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For those who are using this integration for deployment purposes this, I suggest you use the Heroku-cli to deploy in meanwhile they fix their issue

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-cli

Comment: Sure, but can i get the reason why we are not setting up our git to Heroku

Comment: I have the same issues for almost 2 weeks now, did you manage to solve this?

Comment: Yes, As I mentioned above I deployed my code on Heroku server instead of Github